# Docker cadvisor connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, cadvisor

I'm having this issue with docker compose running cadvisor and prometheus.

DNS resolution is working for cadvisor

[image: Ping working using DNS Name for container][image: Prometheus is able to ping cadvisor but telnet to private ip or container name being refused]

When internet is allowed for cadvisor, prometheus is able to connect to agent using public-ip:8081.

````
 version: '3.7' networks:   monitoring:
        driver: bridge volumes:   prometheus_data: {} services:   prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus:latest
        user: "1000"
        environment:
          - PUID=1000
          - PGID=1000
        container_name: prometheus
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
          - /home/sammantar/sammantar/Project/OpenSourceMonitoring/promgrafnode/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
          - /home/sammantar/sammantar/Project/OpenSourceMonitoring/promgrafnode/prometheus:/prometheus
        command:
          - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
          - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
          - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
          - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
          - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
        ports:
          - "9090:9090"
        networks:
          - monitoring


  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8081:8080"
#    network_mode: "host" 
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      mode: global
    networks:
      - monitoring
```
````

Is there any allowed-ip list in the cadvisor or a issue with iptables.

```
yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus" (Working)
    scrape_interval: 1m
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "node" (Working)
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["node-exporter:9100"]

  - job_name: "cadvisor" (not working)
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["cadvisor:8081"]
```

Tried to using private ip address for cadvisor container, connection refused
Tried using container alias name, connection refused
Published cadvisor contianer to internet, connection accepted to public-ip:8081

I don't want to publish cadvisor over internet.

[image]

[RESOLVED]

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus" (Working)
    scrape_interval: 1m
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "node" (Working)
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["node-exporter:9100"]

  - job_name: "cadvisor" (not working)
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["cadvisor:**8080**"]
```

I thought the mapped port on the left side was used when containers connect to each other. 8081:8080, switched to 8080 and it worked thanks to @anemyte

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you're using port 8081, which is available from the host due to port mapping you've configured in docker-compose. Try changing port to 8080 in you cadvisor scrape config.

Comment: I have other serivce mapped to port 8080. I tried using port 8021 and not working as well

Comment: I mean this port mapping changes how you connect from the host, it does not affect how the app listens on internal network.

Comment: changed the scrape file and reboot container. 
  scrape_interval: 1m

scrape_configs: 
  - job_name: "prometheus" 
    scrape_interval: 1m 
    static_configs: 
    - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "node" 
    static_configs: 
    - targets: ["node-exporter:9100"]

  - job_name: "cadvisor" 
    scrape_interval: 5s 
    static_configs: 
    - targets: ["cadvisor:8021"]

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it worked. Thanks